# Circleci.yml empty dependencies override run default commands

Tags: ios, circleci

I use a circleci.yml file to  configure a CircleCI builds for iOS project

The "dependencies" section run by default "Fetch Cocoapods Repo" from a S3 server, which takes almost 3 minutes.

I want to disable this default command for this section with following definition:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    - gem update fastlane
    - fastlane --version
  override:
  cache_directories:
    - "~/.cocoapods"
compile:
  override:
    - fastlane scan    
test:
  override:
```

The problem is that the section "dependencies": with "override" keyword run a default command "Fetch Cocoapods Repo".

**The question is:** To avoid running default commands under a section, Is it enough to add keyword "override"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't work on it's own, but changing the `override` line to the following would

`override:
    - echo "Skipping Cocoapods fetch"`